# Facebook SDK (5.0) - Graph API Request - Pagination (How to get ALL results)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, infinite-loop

I'm working on a simple Facebook app that needs to get ALL of a user's Page likes in order to compare them to a list of pre-built list of Page id's as a matching identifier.

I can get a list of likes; however, I can only get 100 likes "per page" within the response.  Some of these people have thousands of likes, so I need to ensure I can collect all of the data from all of the pages.

A simple $fb->next($response); will get me the next page (so instead of 100 likes, I can get 200).. but, when I throw that into a loop my script gets stuck in an infinite loop as there seems to *always* be a "next" page even though there are no results present.

Is there any built-in way to easily loop through these results, or am I going to have to check the request-level data structure each iteration for whether or not the items have returned data?

```
//this results in an infinite loop

$request = $fb->request('GET', '/'.$fid['id'].'/likes?limit=9999');

do {
    $graphNode = $fb->getClient()->sendRequest($request);
    $paging = $graphNode->getGraphEdge();
    $graphEdge = $graphNode->getGraphEdge()->asArray();     
    $likes = array_merge($likes, $graphEdge);
} while ($fb->next($paging)); // ERROR IS HERE!!  SET while($paging = $fb->next($paging)); INSTEAD
```

UPDATED BELOW VIA RESPONSE COMMENT:

```
        $request = $fb->request('GET', '/'.$fid['id'].'/likes?limit=9999');
    $graphNode = $fb->getClient()->sendRequest($request);
    $graphEdge = $graphNode->getGraphEdge();

    if ($fb->next($graphEdge)) {  

        $likesArray = $graphEdge->asArray();
        $lc = count($likesArray);
        $totalLikes = array_merge($totalLikes, $likesArray); 

        while ($graphEdge = $fb->next($graphEdge)) { 

            $likesArray = $graphEdge->asArray();
            $lic = count($likesArray);
            $totalLikes = array_merge($totalLikes, $likesArray);

        }

    } else {

        $likesArray = $graphEdge->asArray();
        $totalLikes = array_merge($totalLikes, $likesArray);

    }
```

Comment: How are you using the `limit` field? I am getting that it's a non-existing field at least in v3.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what i've always used. You could always use the loop is a function by changing the $likes variable into $data parameter and passing through other GraphEdge calls through the function.

```
$getPages = $this->fb->get('/me/likes?limit=100');
$likes = $getPages->getGraphEdge();

$totalLikes = array();

        if ($this->fb->next($likes)) {  
            $likesArray = $likes->asArray();
            $totalLikes = array_merge($totalLikes, $likesArray); 
            while ($likes = $this->fb->next($likes)) { 
                $likesArray = $likes->asArray();
                $totalLikes = array_merge($totalLikes, $likesArray);
            }
        } else {
            $likesArray = $likes->asArray();
            $totalLikes = array_merge($totalLikes, $likesArray);
        }

        return $totalLikes;
```

Comment: What type of object is your $data?  I implemented this, but it's seemingly no different than my implementation.  If there is more than one page at all, it gets stuck within an infinite loop.  It seems that $fb->next($data) always has a "next" as long as there is more than one page.

Comment: Take out your do while loop and change your likes code to use these 2 lines. Look at answer for edits

Comment: also i did leave a $data symbol after the while call. Change that to $likes. My fault

Comment: I added my latest code to the bottom of the original post.  The count inside the while loop repeatedly prints out "100" over and over and over.. like it's looping through the same page infinitely.  I only have 115 likes on this test account so it should only have to loop through two pages.

Comment: I found the error!  I wasn't setting the while data to my next.  Latest code has been posted.  Thanks so much for your help, Juakali.

Answer (score 1):

Or easy way :

```
do {
    foreach ($response->asArray() as $item){
        //do something with it
    }
} while($response = $facebookApp->next($response));
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Alborq mentioned, I think it makes more sense to use a `do while` loop like this:

```
$apiData = [];
$response = $fb->get($endpoint);
$edge = $response->getGraphEdge(); 
do {
    $arrayFromThisEdge = $edge->asArray();
    $apiData = array_merge($apiData, $arrayFromThisEdge);
} while ($edge = $fb->next($edge));
return $apiData;
```

(Unfortunately, in [my particular case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57454155/470749), I think there might be a Facebook bug.)